# How to set timezone when executing odoo cron schedule action once a day

Tags: python, cron, odoo

In my odoo module I have created scheduled action with cron that must be executed once a day at a certain hour (15:20). But the action is running two hours late. Maybe this is related to the timezone.
The timezone of the server is Europe/Madrid.
The hour is vie 08 abr 2022 04:35:52 CEST.

How can I fix this?

Here is my code

```
 <record id="cron_read_asp_15_files" model="ir.cron">
            <field name="name">Portabilidad Read ASP 15 R files </field>
            <field name="active" eval="True" />
            <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root" />
            <field name="interval_number">1</field>
            <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
            <field name="doall">-1</field>
           <field ref="model_portabilidad_request" name="model_id" />
           <field name="state">code</field>
           <field name="code">model.action_read_asp_15_files()</field>
           <field eval="False" name="doall"/>
           <field name="function">True</field>
           <field name="nextcall" eval="(DateTime.now() + timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 15:20:00')" />
           <field name="interval_type">days</field>
        </record>
```